# Linear mixed effects model methodology suggestions

Tags: r, mixed-model, biostatistics

4 beehives were equipped with sensors that collected temp, humidity, pressure, decibels inside the hive. these are the response variables.

the treatment was wifi exposure, the experimental groups were exposed to wifi from day 1 to day 20, then again from day 35-45, and data was collected until day day 54. n of hives = 4, n of data collected by sensors in each hive = ~million. "wifi" is a dichotomous variable (1=on 0=off) that corresponds to the time of exposure, and treatment hive is another dichotomous variable for the hives exposed to wifi (1=exposure, 0=control).

The goal is to determine if the wifi treatments had an effect on the response variables. The effect does necessary correspond to the time of wifi exposure.

```
names(Hives)
[1] "time"           "dht22_t"        "dht11_t"        "dht22_h"       
[5] "dht11_h"        "db"             "pa"             "treatment_hive"
[9] "wifi
```

Data was also collected on area of honey storage in cm^2 on day 6 and 28. for each day, each hive has 20 data points (=10 frames, double sided). I am not too sure how to incorporate this as it only occurred twice.

I have run a linear mixed effects model

```r
> model2 <- lme(pa ~ wifi*treatment_hive, 
              random= ~ 1|treatment_hive/time, 
                    data = Hives, na.action=na.exclude)
    > summary(model2)
    Linear mixed-effects model fit by REML
     Data: Hives 
           AIC      BIC    logLik
      51750.65 51793.24 -25868.33

    Random effects:
     Formula: ~1 | treatment_hive
            (Intercept)
    StdDev:    16.39396

     Formula: ~1 | time %in% treatment_hive
            (Intercept) Residual
    StdDev:    660.3532 247.6325

    Fixed effects: pa ~ wifi * treatment_hive 
                            Value Std.Error   DF   t-value p-value
    (Intercept)         100555.88  32.49260 3241 3094.7323  0.0000
    wifi                   126.14  43.75924 3241    2.8826  0.0040
    treatment_hive         452.52  41.40820    0   10.9282     NaN
    wifi:treatment_hive     79.92  53.47412 3241    1.4945  0.1351
     Correlation: 
                        (Intr) wifi   trtmn_
    wifi                -0.554              
    treatment_hive      -0.785  0.434       
    wifi:treatment_hive  0.453 -0.818 -0.532

    Standardized Within-Group Residuals:
            Min          Q1         Med          Q3         Max 
    -0.87249020 -0.26487688  0.05674425  0.28952796  0.69706926 

    Number of Observations: 3245
    Number of Groups: 
              treatment_hive time %in% treatment_hive 
                           2                     3245
```

I intend to run this model for each response variable, but am not sure if there are more suitable ways to model this data.

Comment: When you say "a linear effects model" do you mean a linear mixed effects model?

Comment: Yes yes sorry.the fixed effects is wifi and random effects are treatment hives and time. I will edit OP and change typo.

Comment: The 0 df for treatment_hive is problematic. There are 4 hives in the study so df = 3. So i think the model needs to be changed to reflect this, but don't know how. should an additional column be added for each hive, and this be added to the model as a random effect?